# the difference in dealing of Layer 3 Switch and Router with broadcast communication

Tags: switch, router, layer3, broadcast

How does L3 Switch deal with broadcast communication such as ARP,DHCP or Broadcast storm? Is it the same that router deal with such as blocking a broadcast communication or ip address "255.255.255.255"?

Comment: Can you make your questioner clearer please?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

By default, a layer 3 switch will treat broadcasts like a layer 2 switch at the layer 2 level.  IOW, it will forward the broadcast throughout the VLAN.  By default, it will treat broadcasts like a router at the layer 3 level.  IOW, it will not forward broadcasts across layer 3 boundaries.